# c# Command Line arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am trying to make my program run from commands line arguments, so i have 3 options in my code that you can choose to run.

The question is that i want to parse the port along with the arguments, how do i do that?

Each option has a different program configuration. My attempt show below; so inside the the program i also want to pass the the port as a argument so when i write "program 1 5656" in the console. The application sees that its the first option 1 to run and then parses the 5656 into the port variable.

I tried below but when i enter the command it gives me the wrong option as in it start option 2 instead of 1.

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test if input arguments were supplied:
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(args[1]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(args[2]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
        if (args.Length == 3)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(args[3]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so whats the question?

Comment: The question is that i want to parse the port along with the arguments, how do i do that? (Updated the question

Comment: arrays are 0 indexed

Comment: "it gives me the wrong option" doesn't describe exactly what you're doing or what you're seeing.

Comment: So when i type "program 1 1234" it actually starts option 3

Comment: @Sayse so you mean that i should start at 0? in the port parts?

Comment: args[1] wont exist if length=1, its args[0], so if you run "program 1 2" thats 2 parameters for program..... but you would know this if you traced your program and looked at args..

Comment: ah think i got confused, right so how do i make it so that when the first argument is "1" and the second argument is "1234" it runs the first program and puts 1234 into the port variable. I mean for each one section there should be only 1 argument for the option and another for the port. Therefore 2 argument, i put arg[0] at the port but how do i make the programs selected by a number ? so i can actually choose which configuration to run.

Comment: I would suggest investigating possibility in using http://commandline.codeplex.com/ it offers greater flexibility and you even can display the options with a specialized attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this, what you want?

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test if input arguments were supplied:
        var switchvalue = int.Parse(args[0]);
        if (switchvalue == 1)
                {
            int port = int.Parse(args[1]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
        if (switchvalue == 2)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(args[1]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
        if (switchvalue == 3)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(args[1]);
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            //Rest of the program
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of like that but when i type "program 1 1234" it just hangs, no errors. When i run on Vstudio it gives me Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Ahh yeah forgot to change the args to 1. It works now. It was hard to explain what i was wanting but thank you. Didnt know that you can easily use a switch statement to pass as a arg[0]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you want `port` being the *last* parameter:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {  
    // if we have parameters...
    if (args.Length > 0) { 
      //TODO: int.TryParse is a better choice
      int port = int.Parse(args[args.Length - 1]); // ... port is the last one
      server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
      // Rest of the program
    }
  }
```

**Edit**: if you want to pass *just two parameters* (`option` and `port`)

```
  static void Main(string[] args) { 
    if (args.Length == 2) {
      //TODO: int.TryParse is a better choice 
      int option = int.Parse(args[0]);
      int port = int.Parse(args[1]);

      // Rest of the program, e.g.
      if (option == 1) {
        ...  
      } 
      else if (option == 2) {
        ...
      }
      else if (option == 3) {
        ...
      }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: So that allows me to select the each configuration, so if i choose option one i would write "program 1 1234" 1 being the first config/option and 1234 being the last parameter for port.

Comment: @Freon: Yes, as far as I can see from your code, you're looking for something like that, with `port` being the last parameter

Comment: Because like before i had it via user input on console, so like if (option == "1"){//Rest of program} . Now i want to do the same but just passing the parameters. Anyway when i run your version it always gives me the first option, i cant choose option 2

Comment: @Freon: in this case, first read exactly two parameters (`option` and `port`) and then put the `if` on `option` value, not on `args.Length`; see my edit

Comment: Thanks, i realised i could still use if statements/switch statements